# The group of automorphisms of the unit disk

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Does the group of (conformal) automorphisms of the complex unit disk have a normal subgroup? (different from the identity and the group itself)

Comment: at least two ....

Comment: Why at least two?

Comment: e and G $ \hspace{1cm} $

Comment: The question is about subgroups different from those.

Comment: You should write non trivial proper normal subgroups, anyways, show some of your try, or it will be closed soon. Tell us what are you ideas or possible suspects?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth I think 'non-trivial' can be assumed when someone asks a 'are there any subgroups?' question because those are pretty self-evident.

Comment: Note that this group is just $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R) ) and you may have more luck finding answers if you look with that phrase...

Comment: No it wont have any normal subgroups, as $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is simple, see [proof](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~lenfuchs/250A/PSL2Rsimple.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.

As Bhaskar mentions, of course the trivial group and the entire group are normal. But if you're interested, the group of automorphisms of the unit disk is actually quiet small, and can actually be computed explicitly, with a unique representation as a rotation composed with a Blaschke factor. See [here](http://planetmath.org/ProofOfConformalMobiusCircleMapTheorem) for a proof, or the conformal mappings chapter in Stein and Shakarchi if you want something more fleshed out.

Then all the automorphisms are [Mobius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), and it's not hard to see we can actually identify it with $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, which is certainly a simple Lie group, so any normal subgroup must be discrete. I suspect it's a simple group as well, since its discrete subgroups will all look like the modular group and its subgroups, and none of those seem to be normal. This shouldn't be too hard to work out explicitly.

Comment: Peter, can you please explain why do you say:...any normal subgroup must be discrete. Also, I would appreciate if you can give me information about: ...its discrete subgroups will look like the modular group and its subgroups. Thank you.

Comment: Essentially by definition, a simple Lie algebra's only nontrivial normal subgroups are discrete. The discrete subgroups of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ look like $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ (the modular group) and its congruence subgroups $\Gamma(n)$, which are well-documented due to their ubiquity in various applications in number theory.

Comment: Hi Peter, do you have a reference where I can read about these normal subgroups of PSL(2,R) ?  Thank you